# How Sequential Quadratic Programming versus Quadratic programming and Iterative QP are related?

Tags: quadratic-programming

What is the difference between Sequential Quadratic Programming (SQP) versus Quadratic Programming (QP)? Is it the same as Iterative Quadratic Programming (IQP)? For example, BFGS, DFP are types of QP/IQP. Are they also SQP? An IQP is a QP. Is any SQP also an IQP?

Comment: Mathoverflow or math.stackexchange,  which of them is more suitable for this question? See the following: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322230/how-sequential-quadratic-programming-versus-quadratic-programming-and-iterative
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3096387/how-sequential-quadratic-programming-versus-quadratic-programming-and-iterative

Comment: You may also consider asking at: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com